# Improve recovery time of discrete bjt monostable multivibrator

Tags: bjt

How can you improve the recovery time of a monostable multivibrator build of discrete pnp BJT transistors?

I can't use integrated circuits like 555 timer since I need to tolerate voltages up to 36V.

Comment: A circuit schematic or link would help. There's many different ways to build a monostable multivibrator. Lacking more info, usually you reduce recovery time by reducing RC time constants, i.e. lowering R or C.

Comment: Why not use a 555 with a driver?

Comment: I can't use the 555 since I want to avoid an additional voltage regulator while tolerating 4.5V to up to 36V. This voltage range rules out even a simple zener regulator... so I am stuck with a discrete solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivibrator#Monostable_multivibrator_circuit

If you use the circuit shown there, it tells you that the recovery time is given by:
t = ln(2)R2C1. To decrease pulse time simply reduce R2 or C1 and it will shorten how long you're in the temporarily stable state. To reduce what you refer to as recovery time, you should be able to reduce R1. The issue you speak of in the comments would occur due to a non-zero rise time on the left side of C1. If you have high voltage BJT's, you could potentially reduce this rise time to virtually 0 by replacing R1 with a PNP (in your case an NPN) then have a resistor tied between the base of that transistor and the node between R3 and R4. this would create a BJT inverter to drive the left side of the capacitor rapidly between 0V and +V.

Obviously, if you want to use PNP's you'll have to mirror/flip the circuit vertically and replace the NPN's with PNP's.

[image]

Comment: In fact I do exactly as you suggest. I didn't include the schematic since I am typing from my mobile. Is there a way to reduce the recovery time of this basic monoflop?

Comment: Added the answer to that within my answer. You would reduce R2 or C1.

Comment: Maybe I misused the terminology. I know that I can adjust the pulse length by R2*C1. However,  when triggering shortly after the end of the pulse, successive pulses are notably shorter. I am looking for a way to remedy this effect.

Comment: Ah, I understand you now. The question makes a lot more sense now. I've updated the answer to reflect that.